# Should Twitter API requests be sent from the server or from the client?

Tags: api, twitter, access-token

I want to create a Twitter application which would use 'Sign in with Twitter' in order to get the users' access tokens. I then want to perform calls to the API on their behalf.

Should the API requests be sent from the client side, or from the server side?
Rate limits shouldn't make a difference because they are measured per user access token.

But I'm wondering if I'm forgetting other important factors because I'm very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

If your client is a web browser, then the answer is no. Twitter API does not support CORS headers. Have the client connect to a server, and make your requests on the backend.